# logo and title of page floated left but the nav and part of the main content is in the way

Tags: html, css

I floated a logo image and the title of the page to the left, but then the `nav` gets in the way along with some of the main content. I tried to clear the `nav` but then when I want to display my `nav`s inline it will throw it off. So I can't do that.

Anyone know what to do?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header,nav,section,article,aside,footer {
  display: block;
}
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main_header img {
  float: left;
}
.main_header h1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="main_header">
  <img src="logo2.jpg" alt="logo pic">
  <h1>Title of header</h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
header{clear:both; overflow:hidden;}
nav ul li {display:inline;}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header,nav,section,article,aside,footer {
  display: block;
}
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main_header img {
  float: left;
}
.main_header h1 {
  float: left;
}
header{clear:both; overflow:hidden;}
nav ul li {display:inline;}
```

```html
<header class="main_header">
  <img src="logo2.jpg" alt="logo pic">
  <h1>Title of header</h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```